# Is there an established algorithm for reaching a goal through the sequential application of known cause and effect tuples?

Tags: algorithm, simulation

Let's say that I want to create a fictional product called `g`.

I know that:

```
a+b=c
x+y=z
and finally that
c+z=g
```

So clearly if I start off with products

```
a,b,x,y
```

I can create `g` in three steps:

```
a+b=c
x+y=z
c+z=g
```

So a naive algorithm for reaching a goal could be:

For each component required to make the goal (here `c` and `z`), recursively find a cause and effect tuple that can create that component.

But there are snags with that algorithm.

For example, let's say that my cause and effect tuples are:

```
a+b=c
x+y+c=z (NOTE THE EXTRA 'c' REQUIRED!!)
c+z=g
```

Now when I run my naive algorithm I will do

```
a+b=c
x+y+c=z (Using up the 'c' I created in the previous step)
c+z=g (Uh oh! I can't do this because I don't have the 'c' any more)
```

It seems like quite a basic area of research - how we can combine known causes and effects to reach a goal - so I suspect that work must have been done on it, but I've looked around and couldn't find anything and I don't really know where to look now.

Many thanks for any assistance!

Comment: What is the expected dimensionality (how many number of products are you expecting to have?) If this number is pretty small, a recursive (and Dynamic Programming) solution could solve it nicely.

Comment: Thanks @amit, there's no particular use case I'm aiming at, this is purely exploring the problem out of interest, and perhaps because of what it might suggest about how the brain goes about solving similar problems of planning sequences of actions towards a goal. Definitely a brute-force approach would find the solution - I just need to take all the cause/effect tuples and try all the permutations including repetitions. But I doubt that's the most efficient solution, especially as you suggest as the dimensionality increases. I think there's hidden tricky end cases when working backwards though

Comment: [Modus ponens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modus_ponens) is the basis of what you seek. A programming language that can support such is [Prolog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prolog). You should also look at [Causality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causality) and [Ontology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ontology_(information_science)).

Comment: With regards to `how the brain goes` then you are stepping from a [Closed World assumption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-world_assumption) into an [Open World assumption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-world_assumption). Any way that is enough terms to put you into the ball park of what you seek.

Comment: Thanks so much @GuyCoder, I will follow up on these. That looks perfect..

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what you mean by effect, cause and the steps? Is it like "c" and "z" prerequisites required to achieve "g"?

Comment: Yes, @YeldarKurmangaliyev. To be clearer, if you have two objects, c and z, when you combine them, you get an object g (and c and z have gone). g could also be potentially be achieved by other means, but combining c and z yields g.

Comment: I think you can represent these as a directed unweighted graph. So, A -> C, B -> C, X -> Z, Y -> Z, C -> Z, C -> G, Z -> G. You can then start from G and perform [topological sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) to find the correct order of dependencies. You will have to tweak it to make it support this "have gone" logic, so you probably will have to make sure that no node is reused by two edges.

Comment: Thanks @YeldarKurmangaliyev, I will look into that. I suspect that it will be the tweaks that make it hard. For example, in the real world of creating such causal chains, it is not necessarily a problem if an earlier step uses up something needed by a later step, provided that another step can be found to create the missing product. For example, if I'm cooking and I need butter for the frying pan, but I also need the butter for the meatballs, that's ok if I have some milk too that I can make into butter. So a simple rule that says a node can't be used more than once is too restrictive.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that using a product consumes one item of it, which can then be replaced by producing a second item of that product, I would model this by giving each product a cost and working out how to minimize the cost of the final product. In this case I think this is the same as minimizing the costs of every product, because minimizing the cost of an input never increases the cost of any output. You end up with loads of equations like

a=min(b+c, d+e, f+g)

where a is the cost of a product that can be produced in alternative ways, one way consuming units with cost of b and c, another way consuming units with costs of d and e, another way consuming units with costs of f and g, and so on. There may be cycles in the associated graph.

One way to solve such a problem would be to start by assigning the cost infinity to all products not originally provided as inputs (with costs) and then repeatedly reducing costs where equations show a way of calculating a cost less than the current cost, keeping track of re-calculations caused by inputs not yet considered or reductions in costs. At each stage I would consider the consequences of the smallest input or recalculated value available, with ties broken by a second component which amounts to a tax on production. The outputs produced from a calculation are always at least as large as any input, so newly produced values are always larger than the recalculated value considered, and the recalculated value considered at each stage never decreases, which should reduce repeated recalculation.

Another way would be to turn this into a linear program and throw it at a highly optimized guaranteed polynomial time (at least in practice) linear programming solver.

a = min(b+c, d+e, f+g)

becomes

a = b+c-x

a = d+e-y

a = f+g-z

x >= 0

y >= 0

z >= 0

minimize sum(x+y+z+....)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It's rather advanced for me, I'm not familiar with linear programming solvers but it's given me some good direction about where to look and I will circle back to it as I get deeper into this.

Comment: I would like to think that - at least in practice - the sort of updating approach I described before mentioning linear programming will solve this problem in an acceptable time. I believe that this is the case when all of the coefficients in the equations are >= 1, as described above. I mentioned linear programming mostly to make a mathematical argument that this way of looking at costs leads to a tractable problem, while still hoping that the full generality of linear programming would not be necessary.